# Should I overwrite contentEditable as "true" for my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contenteditable

I was making a chrome extension for DOM manipulation, specifically highlight/underline/line-through/add textarea to write a short summary of the page - nothing to change the text content itself. For dev purposes only, I was matching for `*.notion.site/*`.

I realized that just this morning, they had added `contentEditable=false` properties to each of their `<div>` and parts of my existing code was no longer working. Now my first reaction was just "ok, there must be a way using javascript to overwrite this attribute to make it 'true' and then I can re-execute my manipulations." But then before I started digging into the fix, I started wondering about the broader question here - should I be doing that for this site?

Understand the way I phrased that is very ambiguous and at this point it's more just a personally moral? gray area? question, but does anyone with more experience have any opinions as to whether I should start using different URLs for something like this?

Comment: nothing you do in your "extension" changes that site, it just changes how YOU see the site - so, go ahead, go nuts :p

Comment: There's no moral aspect here at all. Just make sure your changes don't break the site's behavior for the users of your extension.